# How money transfer work from app to bank account

Tags: flutter, payment, bank, onlinebanking

I want to transfer money from flutter app (my bank account) to Direct bank account of user . I want to withdraw with bank of america how can I got the APIs for it as most of the money transfer app do.

Comment: To do this, you need to make sure that your user has an account with "account_balance" as a field and then use their Transaction API to send the funds. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77232316/19420551) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure at all but I think that you need to acces to this page
[Bank Of America Developer](https://developer.bankofamerica.com/CPODevPortal/apidocs/public/#/home) they have an extensive documentation to guide you.

Good Luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).